# Parsing and validating an XML with namespaces in JAVA

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing

I have the following SOAP Message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sch="http://test.testMessage.com/v2/TestMessage/schema">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sch:input>
         <sch:header>
               <sch:MessageName>ChangePurchaseOrder</sch:MessageName>
           </sch:header>
         <sch:payload>
           <sch:xmlData>
           </sch:xmlData>
         </sch:payload>
     </sch:input>
   </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to parse it (with namespaces) and get just the "input" node into a new document. like below:

```
<sch:input xmlns:sch="http://test.testMessage.com/v2/TestMessage/schema">
     <sch:header>
           <sch:MessageName>ChangePurchaseOrder</sch:MessageName>
       </sch:header>
     <sch:payload>
       <sch:xmlData>
       </sch:xmlData>
     </sch:payload>
 </sch:input>
```

I am trying to extract that part of the message. Can anyone help me to extract the section of code shown in the second snippet from the first?

I tried something like this so far: 
    NodeList inputNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(namespaceURI, "sch:input");

but when I do
    int length = inputNodeList.getLength();

I get the value for "length" as 0, where as, it is supposed to be 1. Any help will be appreciated!

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set your [DocumentBuilderFactor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html) to be [name space awar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setNamespaceAware%28boolean%29)e, and implement your own [NameSpaceContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext.html). It would be less painful if you use a soap client instead of manually parsing the xml.